# Changing action bar searchview hint text color

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

How can I change the action bar search view hint text colour?

This question explains how to get the EditText when using ABS:
[Android ActionBar Customize Search View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137141/android-actionbar-customize-search-view)

Is there a android.R.id I could use to get a reference to the EditText so I could change the hint colour? Or is there some other way to change the colour?

[image: Action bar search view hint text]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`android:actionBarWidgetTheme` of your main theme should point to a style that has a `android:textColorHint` in it. That one will allow changing the hint text color of the search view.

Comment: `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` is available only at API lvl 14.

Comment: The solution doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14364222 does, but it's really a workaround.

Comment: Ill just add a comment here, the parent for `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` style is a theme also. You can use `@android:style/Theme.Holo` for the lighter search icon, and `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` for the darker search icon. From [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.co.nz/2012/11/the-unknown-style-actionbarwidgettheme.html)

Comment: am using material3 searchbar. I got this working by setting android:textAppearance="@style/CustomSearchBarStyle" Hope this will help someone looking for a solution.

Answer (score 67):

```
searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hintSearchMess) + "</font>"));
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation?

Comment: What's not to understand? Change the color of text and hint text via html tags ...

Comment: can we change font size using html.fromhtml?

Comment: If you need only different size, you can use simple <small> or <big>

Answer (score 26):

```
SearchView searchView= (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
int id = searchView.getContext()
                   .getResources()
                   .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Nice to know, how to find search_src_text.
Thanks.

Comment: This solution works for the actual search text, but does not affect the hint text color.

Comment: it works with me in its time don't knew by now :) sorry for that @GraydynYoung

Answer (score 18):

this worked for me, hope it helps

```
((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

[also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786726/change-text-color-of-search-hint-in-actionbar-using-support-library)

Comment: I found that `android.support.v7.appcompat` is not necessary, just use `searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)` is ok.

Answer (score 12):

I resolved it adding this property to the main theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    .....
    .....
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarWidgetTheme</item> 
</style>
```

And then add the property i want to change in this case the hint color.

```
<style name="MyActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    .....
    .....
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/blanco_60</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: "android:actionBarWidgetTheme requires API level 14"

Comment: Yes! With theming!

Comment: This does not work  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 9):

Here's specifically how you apply the style as hinted at above.  The right answer is to overload the action bar widget style with your own custom style.  For holo light with dark action bar, put this in your own styles file such as `res/values/styles_mytheme.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Widget</item>
    <!-- your other custom styles -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- your other custom widget styles -->
</style>
```

Make sure your application is using theme custom theme as described in [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 7):

A `SearchView` object extends from `LinearLayout`, so it holds other views. The trick is to find the view holding the hint text and change the colour programmatically. By traversing the view hierarchy, you can find the widget containing the hint text:

```
// get your SearchView with its id
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
// traverse the view to the widget containing the hint text
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout)ll.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout ll3 = (LinearLayout)ll2.getChildAt(1);
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)ll3.getChildAt(0);
// set the hint text color
autoComplete.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(Color.WHITE));
```

This method works with any theme. Also, you can change the look of other widgets in the `SearchView` hierarchy, such as the `EditText` holding the search query.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change left arrow button in search view, add app:collapseIcon.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_search_view_home"
        />
```

If you want to change text color and text hint color, add the following.

```
EditText searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If you want to change close icon, add the following.

```
ImageView imvClose = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id
            .search_close_btn);
    imvClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_view_close);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just get the `textView` id of search widget and use `setTextColor()` method to change the search text color and `setHintTextColor()` to change the search hints text color.

```
// Get textview id of search widget
int id =  searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);

// Set search text color
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

// Set search hints color
textView.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: Best Solution ever

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me :-)

```
 EditText seartext = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    seartext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    seartext.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: Try don't use uppercase letters when it's not necessary. Doing that sends your comment to review queue, what let people like me (and you in future) reviewing a post that don't have nothing wrong (only the uppercase...).

Answer (score 5):

With the most recent appcompat library (or if you're targeting 5.0+), this is possible to do purely in XML using a `ThemeOverlay`:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.AutoCompleteTextView.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.AutoCompleteTextView.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#5000</item>
</style>
```

And then in your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar"
    ... />
```

If you also want it to apply to activities that are using an `ActionBar` instead of a `Toolbar`, you can add this to the `Activity`'s theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Except I created a new theme "SearchViewStyle" which inherits from my main app theme and then added it to my SearchView component like this: "android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"

Comment: yes, starting from 5 Android such things should be using app compat themes/styles, and support libraries which includes all of this are available for older versions as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. It is very easy.

```
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
           searchEditText.setHint("Search");
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

**searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));**

Answer (score 2):

Look to this class, it can help you to solve your problem

```
import android.R.color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.SearchAutoComplete;

public class MySearchView {

    public static SearchView getSearchView(Context context, String strHint) {
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
        searchView.setQueryHint(strHint);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        searchView.requestFocus();
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

        ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_button);
        searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_search);

        // ImageView searchBtnClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_close_btn);
        // searchBtnClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel_search_bar);


        SearchAutoComplete searchText = (SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
        setFont(context, searchText);
        searchText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(color.white));
        searchText.setHintTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(color.white));

        return searchView;
    }

    private static void setFont(Context _context, SearchAutoComplete searchText) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        Typeface currentType = searchText.getTypeface();
        if (currentType == null) {
            tf = MyApplication.fontNormal;
        }
        else {
            int currentStyle = currentType.getStyle();
            if (currentStyle == Typeface.BOLD) {
                tf = MyApplication.fontBold;
            }
            else if (currentStyle == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) {
                tf = MyApplication.fontBoldItalic;
            }
            else if (currentStyle == Typeface.ITALIC) {
                tf = MyApplication.fontItalic;
            }
            else {
                tf = MyApplication.fontNormal;
            }
        }
        searchText.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    public static SearchView getSearchView(Context context, int strHintRes) {
        return getSearchView(context, context.getString(strHintRes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using this you can change the Searchable xml

1. Search text hint color
2. Search Text
3. Search close icon
4. Search hint icon
5. Search plate

> ```
> int searchHintBtnId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
>                     .getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
>      int hintTextId = searchView.getContext()
>                     .getResources()
>                     .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
>             int closeBtnId = searchView.getContext()
>                     .getResources()
>                     .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
>             // Set the search plate color to white
>             int searchPlateId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
>
>             View view = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
>             view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_plate);
>
>             ImageView closeIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(closeBtnId);
>             closeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
>
>             ImageView searchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchHintBtnId);
>             searchHintIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
>
>             TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(hintTextId);
>             textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_text_color));
>             textView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_hint_text_color));
> ```

Here is drawable/search_plate.xml

> ```
> <!-- main color -->
> <item android:bottom="1dp"
>     android:left="1dp"
>     android:right="1dp">
>     <shape >
>         <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_color" />
>     </shape>
> </item>
>
> <!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
> <item android:bottom="10.0dp">
>     <shape >
>         <solid android:color="@color/app_theme_color" />
>     </shape>
> </item> </layer-list>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to change color of Search View Hint Text is :

```
 SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
 searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: This is pretty close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29026547/733092 above (but better formatted).

Answer (score 1):

```
int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
textView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple to achieve using the `styles.xml` Just understand that themeing the SearchView is directly related to the theme of the Toolbar from whose `menu.xml` it is fetched as a `app:actionViewClass`.

1. Create a style for Toolbar.
2. Apply that style as theme on the Toolbar
   and it changes al the related views and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set the SearchView on your menuItem manually and thereby have full control over the view.