# How do I change the colour of the text select handles that appear when I'm highlighting text? (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, colors, searchview, android-theme

I'd appreciate your assistance in changing the appearance of the text selection handles, which are the bubbles that appear when highlighting text. Currently, these bubbles seem to replicate the background color in some way, and I'm looking for guidance on how to modify their color.

Issue:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ideNh.jpg)

Somethings I tried:

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@style/CustomTextSelectHandle</item>
```

to theme and the following as a style:

```
<style name="CustomTextSelectHandle">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item></style>
```

Additionally, I have a SearchView in my Android Studio project, and I'd like to change both the text color and the hint color of the SearchView. I attempted a solution from a Stack Overflow post ([Changing action bar searchview hint text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791388/changing-action-bar-searchview-hint-text-color)), but it didn't work for me, or I might have implemented it incorrectly, particularly for changing the hint color of the SearchView. I'd appreciate your help in achieving this customization. Thank you for your support, and let me know if you require further information.
I assume that this is something to do with the themes file. This is my themes file with some stuff extracted:

````
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.GameOn" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="1">@color/background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.GameOn" parent="Base.Theme.GameOn" />
</resources>```
````